# How to schedule a sub jcl from main jcl

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl

For Example while executing and running up a cobol db2 program we need to submit mutilpe jcl, so need to bring all those sub-jcl under my main jcl, so that i need to submit only one jcl and compilation and execution are done.

```
                                      main jcl
                                  -       -      - 
                                  -       -      - 
                                jcl1     jcl2   jcl3
```

Constaints:
I can't update the jcl1, jcl2 and jcl3.

Comment: What have you tried ???. Search on `mainframe internal reader` or `INTRDR` that is the prefered method. You can run TSO in background see https://ibmmainframes.com/about2948.html

Comment: i am trying joblib for the programs to execute and if statement to check program execution step return code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOBLIB` or `STEPLIB` is a list of libraries which contain executables, i.e. programs. They do *not* contain jobs, i.e. JCLs.

There is no such thing as a sub-JCL from an operating point of view. Each job is a separte set of JCL statements, which may be stored as member of JCL libraries, or they may be generated by a program.

If your COBOL program needs to decide when and which job to submit, it needs to know the library and member for each job. It can then read the member from the library and write the records to an *INTRDR* data set. The JCL for the COBOL program could, e.g. contian DD statements for each of the three jobs and a single *INTRDR* DD to submit the jobs.

```
//jobname JOB ....
...
//stepname EXEC PGM=your-cobol-pgm
//...
//JOB1     DD DISP=SHR,DSN=your.jcl.lib(JOB1)
//JOB2     DD DISP=SHR,DSN=your.jcl.lib(JOB2)
//JOB3     DD DISP=SHR,DSN=your.jcl.lib(JOB3)
//SUBMIT   DD SYSOUT=(A,INTRDR)
...
```

I'm not a COBOL programmer, so I won't try to give example code. In the COBOL code, you declare files for each of the jobs, i.e. JOB1, JOB2, and JOB3, and one for the INTRDR, i.e. `SUBMIT` (Note the DD name *SUBMIT* was arbitrarily chosen; it can be almost any name you want).

When it is time to submit job 1, you open files `JOB1`, and `SUBMIT`, then read each record from `JOB1` and immediately write it to `SUBMIT`. Finally, you close both files, and by closing `SUBMIT` you're telling JES to process the job.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore [JES2 Execution Control Statements](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-jes2-execution-control-statements), which would allow you to do all this with JCL.

Answer (score 0):

The best and cleanest way is to put them all in JCL procedures and call them all from a Job.